# Xamarin iOS Bindings Libraries issue with Typedefs

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, objective-sharpie

I'm trying to create à binding library from this project https://github.com/Eclair/CircleProgressBar.

I use sharpie to generate the ApiDefinition.cs and the .a files.

```
> sharpie pod init ios CircleProgressBar
> sharpie bind
```

I copied the .a file in my project and put the generated c# code in my ApiDefinition.cs file.
However the generated code does not compile.

I think that the problem is that, these lines

```
typedef NSString*(^StringGenerationBlock)(CGFloat progress);
typedef NSAttributedString*(^AttributedStringGenerationBlock)(CGFloat progress);
```

Are converted to these

```
delegate string StringGenerationBlock (nfloat arg0);
delegate NSAttributedString AttributedStringGenerationBlock (nfloat arg0);
```

But the compiler suggests to replace string with IntPtr, and even if I do that and even if the project is compiled, my application crashes if I try to instantiate a CircleProgressBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1st:

Change the `string` that is causing the error to an `NSString` (and *not* an IntPtr):

```
// typedef NSString * (^StringGenerationBlock)(CGFloat);
delegate NSString StringGenerationBlock (nfloat arg0);
```

Now the binding project in your solution should compile without errors.

#### 2nd:

Debug/Test on an actual device

By default `sharpie pod XXXXX` is **not** going to create a static library that will work in the iOS Simulator and it also does not allow for creating of **fat** libraries, you would have to do that manually.

#### Create a `iphonesimulator` based static library if desired:

For that you need to manually build the xcode project with the `sdk` set to `iphonesimulator`.

i.e.

```
xcodebuild -project Pods.xcodeproj -target Pods -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug clean build
```

You can use that output with the original `.a` to create a fat lib.

#### Really quick example:

```
if (circleProgressBar == null) {
    circleProgressBar = new CircleProgressBar ();
    circleProgressBar.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (this.View.Frame.Width / 4, this.View.Frame.Width / 4, this.View.Frame.Width / 2, this.View.Frame.Width / 2);
    circleProgressBar.ProgressBarWidth = 33.0f;
    circleProgressBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    circleProgressBar.ProgressBarProgressColor = UIColor.Green;
    circleProgressBar.ProgressBarTrackColor = UIColor.Red;
    circleProgressBar.StartAngle = 0.0f;
    circleProgressBar.SetProgress (0.0f, false);
    this.Add (circleProgressBar);
} else {
    circleProgressBar.SetProgress (circleProgressBar.Progress + 0.1f, true);
}
```

#### Results in:

[image]